# Custom 16 digit ID Generator in Grails Domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Instead of a sequence of ID which GORM creates, I want to use a 16 digit random number as ID for all the tables GORM creates. I need help as to how to do that. I tried doing

static mapping = {
        id generator: 'uuid2'
    }

it didnt work. Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple mapping like:

```
class Book {
    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned'
     }
    def beforeInsert() {
        id = YourRandomGenerator.nextInt()
    }
}
```

Note the use of the beforeInsert event to assign the id.
Greetings.

Comment: Thanks I like both the alternatives provided for this query. Appreciate it very much

Comment: This is definitely not the best approach, see my answer below, for a more generic approach.

Answer (score 9):

If all you want to do is do a custom generator, you can extend IdentifierGenerator:

```
class CustomGenerator extends IdentifierGenerator {
    Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {
        return "myroutine"
    }
}

class Book {
    String id
    static mapping = {
         generator:"some.package.CustomGenerator", column:"id", unique:"true"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like both the alternatives provided for this query. Appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom id generator as shown below

```
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

public synchronized Serializable generate(final SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        return GENERATED ID; //return generated id 
    }
}
```

Now, if you want it to use for some specific domains only..
Then you can do it in mappings closure like this

```
mapping = {
        id generator:'packagename.CustomIdGenerator'
    }
```

But if you want all your domains to use the custom id generator, you can specify it in Config.groovy like this, and it will apply to all the domains

```
grails {
  gorm.default.mapping = {
        id column: 'id', generator:'packagename.CustomIdGenerator'
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you generate id? In your mock code, you have written GENERATED ID, but I'm not sure how to generate the next Id, If I want to do it manually